# Backbonejs: backbone is not defined error

Tags: backbone.js

Google Chrome developer tools console throws this error:

```
uncaught reference error: backbone is not defined
```

When this html file containing javascript with library backbone.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example Backbone APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      Whisky = Backbone.Model.extend();
        firstWhisky = new Whisky({
        name : 'Blenders Pride'
      });
      Whiskies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        Model:Whisky ,
        url:"#"
      });

      first_view = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : 'body',
        initialize : function() { 
          this.$el.empty();
          this.render();
        } , 

        render : function() { 
          this.$el.append("<h1>The Whisky APP</h1>");
          this.list_view = new List_view();
          this.$el.append(this.list_view.render().el);
          return this ; 
        }
      });
      List_view = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        tagName : 'ul' , 
        render : function() {
          this.$el.empty();
          this.$el.append("<li>Royal stag</li>");
          this.$el.append("<li>Signature </li> ");
          return this ; 
        }
      });
      index_view = new first_view();    
    </script>
    <script src="LIB/json2.js"></script> 
    <script src="LIB/underscore-min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work! Since the scripts are interpreted as they are read, order is very important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use Backbone before it's declaration.

Put the `<script>` tags before your own javascript code.

You must re-organize your javascript part like this :

```
<script src="LIB/json2.js"></script> 
<script src="LIB/underscore-min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script> 
<script>
  Whisky = Backbone.Model.extend();
    firstWhisky = new Whisky({
    name : 'Blenders Pride'
  });
  Whiskies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    Model:Whisky ,
    url:"#"
  });



  first_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : 'body',
    initialize : function() { 
      this.$el.empty();
      this.render();
    } , 

    render : function() { 
      this.$el.append("<h1>The Whisky APP</h1>");
      this.list_view = new List_view();
      this.$el.append(this.list_view.render().el);
      return this ; 
    }
  });
  List_view = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    tagName : 'ul' , 
    render : function() {
      this.$el.empty();
      this.$el.append("<li>Royal stag</li>");
      this.$el.append("<li>Signature </li> ");
      return this ; 
    }
  });
  index_view = new first_view();    
</script>
```

Comment: I didnt understand ......can you please explain it in another way .. I'm sry for the inconvenience i'm new to Js and backbone ...

Comment: Your script tag including Backbone is placed after your code using Backbone. So Backbone is not loaded yet when your code is run. Place your script tag before your code, or run your code when the whole page is loaded (with jQuery you can do $(function(){ //your code here}); to have the desired effect).

Answer (score 2):

This might be related. 
I was loading jQuery, Underscore and Backbone to my index.html from http://cdnjs.com  hosted libraries using this links:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

as a result I can get access to $, _  and Backbone in Chrome, but if I try to open the page in  Firefox I get:  Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined..
However when using links provided by Eric Leschinski:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

everything works  fine.

Answer (score 1):

### How to reproduce this error with as few lines as possible:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    });
</script>
<div>mydiv</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You get an error:

```
ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
```

You have not included the necessary backbone libraries.

### If you get this error, then do this Hello world example:

This example has backbone defined:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div>Loading...</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("starting backbone");
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: 'div',
      initialize: function(){
        alert("initializing backbone");    
        this.render();
      },
      render: function(){
        alert("applying text to div attribute");
        this.$el.html("Hello World");
      }
    });
    var appView = new AppView();
    alert("done");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To run this example in a jsfiddle see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfnbK/

It should show 4 popup boxes illustrating the path it takes through the code.  When the render function is called, backbone uses jQuery to replace the contents of the div tag with: "Hello World".